# XSLT: Using sql inner join in xsl

Tags: sql, xslt

How can you do an inner join from a single line? 
Example:

```
<p>
<b>
<xsl:value-of select="tbl_Account/@AccountID" />
</b>
</p>
```

I'd like to grab level name from account ID
So something like this?

```
<p>
<b>
<xsl:value-of select="tbl_Account/INNER JOIN tbl_Level/ON @AccountID = @AccountID/@LevelID" />
</b>
</p>
```

Comment: An example of the source XML and the expected output would be useful.

Comment: Define by what you mean with "source XML example". 
Output: Account ID = 5. LevelID = Standard Account. 

So instead of the output 5 we get Standard Account as an output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You're addressing a community here whose memory of "inner joins" takes us back to a time in our youth when we also knew how to solve simultaneous equations... It would be much better to explain what you actually want to achieve, rather than expressing it in terms of concepts we only distantly remember.

Comment: tbl_Account - contains AccountID. 

I want to find LevelID from tbl_Level by using an inner join from tbl_Account based on accountID. LevelID is a FK in tbl_Level which is a PK on tbl_Account

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is not a database query language and does not do joins. However, it does provide a mechanism to lookup cross-referenced data by using a [key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key).